# How to install linoleum floor under carpet?

Tags: flooring, linoleum

I am replacing an old linoleum floor in my bathroom (replacing it with just another linoleum floor).  It looks like the current linoleum floor was installed prior to the carpeting and the edge by the door is under the carpeting (see the picture below).  How can I remove the old linoleum without damaging how the carpet is attached?  And then when I put the new linoleum down, how can I get it under the carpeting again so the door edge of the linoleum does not roll up?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: In the end I carefully pried up the old carpet edge trim just enough to remove the old piece of linoleum.  I then put in the new linoleum and hammered the carpet edge trim back down on top.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see any nail-heads or screw-heads in the carpet edge trim, so you probably have one like this:

[image: A carpet gripper that is secured underneath the carpet]

You might be able to save it, but they're cheap so I'd just replace it with a new one.  Pry it up taking care not to damage the door trim.  The carpet in the door opening should be loose enough that you can get access to the linoleum underneath (there may be a tack strip across the opening but you should still have a little room to play with). Finish removing the old linoleum flooring, then install the new flooring, gluing it down as you would normally.  Remove the old edge trim from the carpet -- I'm familiar with ones that are folded onto the carpet edge to hold it, so just bend it back.  Install the new one at the edge of the linoleum.  Push the carpet into the new edge trim, making sure it's taut, then bend the trim down to hold the carpet; use a piece of 2x4 cut to the width of the opening so that it bends evenly.